# Удаляются связи ManyToManu в Hibernate!

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jsp, spring-mvc

Всем привет. Делаю небольшое веб приложение, с использованием  Hibernate. Думал что там всё легко и просто, но как оказалось я ошибался. Вот часть сущностей:
Кино

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@NotNull
private int id;

@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
@NotEmpty(message="Не может быть пустым!") 
private String title; 

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 2000)  
@JsonView(ViewMovie.HomeView.class)
private String description;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
@JoinTable(name = "genre_movie", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"))
@JsonView(ViewMovie.HomeView.class) 
private Set<Genre> genre = new HashSet<Genre>();
```

И жанр

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "genre")
 public class Genre {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "GENRE_TITLE")
private String title;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "genre_movie", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"))
private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
```

Так как fetch=LAZY то в настройках hibernate использую "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" = true, как я понимаю это для того, чтобы можно было подгружать ленивую сущность из jsp. Вроде всё хорошо работает, но заметил проблему: КОГДА ПЕРЕХОЖУ НА СТРАНИЦУ ГДЕ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ ПОЛЕ movie.genre то связь genre_movie УДАЛЯЕТСЯ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ.

Причём когда меняю lazy на eager то всё работает хорошо.

Из базы данных фильмы  беру с помощью

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    List<Movie> movies = (List<Movie>) session.createCriteria(Movie.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).list();

    if (!movies.isEmpty()) {
        Movie movie = movies.get(0);
```

жанры таким же образом.
В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте поле id на тип Long в обоих сущностях, потому что при создании типом int у него уже будет значение 0. Связь типа many to many всегда организуется с помощью третьей таблицы. Скорее всего проблема с id.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась указанием JsonView в методах контроллера.

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
 public class Movie implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@NotNull
@JsonView(ViewMovie.ListView.class) 
private int id;

@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
@NotEmpty(message="Не может быть пустым!") 
@JsonView(ViewMovie.ListView.class) 
private String title; 

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 2000)  
@JsonView(ViewMovie.HomeView.class) 
private String description;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
@JoinTable(name = "genre_movie", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"))
@JsonView(ViewMovie.HomeView.class) 
private Set<Genre> genre = new HashSet<Genre>();
```

Теперь в запросах где мне не нужны жанры метод выглядит примерно так

```
        @JsonView(ViewMovie.ListView.class)  
        @RequestMapping(value = "/get_movies/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody List<Movie> getTitlesForPerson( @RequestParam("term") String name) {

        List<Movie> movies = movieService.getMoviesByTitle(name);

        return movies;

    }
```

И не забываем

```
 public class ViewMovie {
    public static class HomeView {}
    public static class ListView {}
```

}